# Got error org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: customers.amountDeposit, customers.amountWithdraw

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, named-query

I have a problem in named query got error `org.hibernate.HibernateException`: Errors in named queries: `customers.amountDeposit`, `customers.amountWithdraw`

Here is my  Namedqueries of deposit and withdrawal of amount and DAO implementation of amountdeposit and amountwithdrawal, tried for the first time, i can say I'm beginner to this

```
    @NamedQueries   ({  
    @NamedQuery(name="customers.amountWithdraw", query="update customers set customerBalance = customerBalance - :amount where :customerAccNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name="customers.amountDeposit", query="update customers set customerBalance = customerBalance + :amount where :customerAccNo" )})
```

And here is my DAO implementation

```
    public Customer amountWithdraw(Customer customer,double amount) {
            customer=(Customer) session.get(Customer.class, customer.getCustomerAccNo());
            if(customer!=null) {
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("customers.amountWithdraw");
            query.setParameter("customerBalance",customer.getCustomerBalance());        
            query.setParameter("amount", amount );
            query.setParameter("customerAccNo",customer.getCustomerAccNo());
            query.executeUpdate();
            customer=getCustomerByAccNo(customer.getCustomerAccNo());
            return customer;
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        public Customer amountDeposit(Customer customer, double amount) {   
            customer=(Customer) session.get(Customer.class, customer.getCustomerAccNo());
            if(customer!=null) {
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("customers.amountDeposit"); 
            query.setParameter("customerBalance",customer.getCustomerBalance());
            query.setParameter("amount", amount );
            query.setParameter("customerAccNo",customer.getCustomerAccNo());
            query.executeUpdate();
            customer=getCustomerByAccNo(customer.getCustomerAccNo());       
            return customer;
            }
            return null;        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `where :customerAccNo` is not a valid predicate. You have to compare that parameter to some column/field with an operator e.g. `=` the equal operator, for this to become a proper predicate. Use this:

```
@NamedQueries   ({  
    @NamedQuery(name="customers.amountWithdraw", query="update customers set customerBalance = customerBalance - :amount where customerAccNo = :customerAccNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name="customers.amountDeposit", query="update customers set customerBalance = customerBalance + :amount where customerAccNo = :customerAccNo" )})
```